# Haskell traverse tree inorder preorder postorder

Tags: haskell, tree

I have the following Haskell data definition:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Int Tree Tree deriving Show
```

and I wrote the following programs to traverse trees preorder, inorder and postorder:

```
preorder(Leaf n) = n
preorder(Node n t0 t1) = [n] ++ preorder t0 ++ preorder t1

inorder(Leaf n) = n
inorder(Node n t0 t1) = inorder t0 ++ [n] ++ inorder t1

postorder(Leaf n) = n
postorder(Node n t0 t1) = postorder t0 ++ postorder t1 ++ [n]
```

The error that I get is:

```
- Type error in application  
*** Expression     : preorder t0 ++ preorder t1  
*** Term           : preorder t1  
*** Type           : Int  
*** Does not match : [a]
```

I need to return a list that contains all tree integers in appropriate order. Any help is highly appreciated as I am new to Haskell.

Answer (score 6):

You're returning `Int` from the base case but `[Int]` from the constructive case.  The leaves should be lists too.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. I need to return a list with all the intergers from the tree. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if this is homework or not.  But:  you're using `[n]` in the recursive cases.  What do you think you should use in the base case, then?

Answer (score 5):

The error is:

```
preorder(Leaf n) = n
```

Should be:

```
preorder(Leaf n) = [n]
```

And same for inorder and postorder.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the functions fixes the error, but you can only insert elements in pairs into your `Tree`.

Better change it to:

```
data Tree = Leaf | Branch Int Tree Tree deriving Show

inorder Leaf = []
inorder (Branch n left right) = inorder left ++ [n] ++ inorder right
-- etc.
```

Nice page to check out algorithm implementations in different languages is Rosetta Code which has a page on [Tree traversals](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Haskell) including in Haskell.